# What does a compiler add to an empty class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, class-design

Suppose, I write

```
class A { };
```

The compiler should provide (as and when needed)

> 1. a constructor
> 2. a destructor
> 3. a copy constructor
> 4. = operator

Is this all the compiler provides?  Are there any additions or deletions to this list?

Comment: I came across this old question just now... for the benefit of future visitors it's probably worth mentioning that in C++11 a move constructor as well as a move assignment operator are auto-generated in addition to the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's complete. But there are two points you should note:

1. It's the *copy* =operator. Just like there is a *copy* constructor, there is a *copy* assignment operator.
2. They are only provided if actually used.

Some explanation for 2:

```
struct A { private: A(); };
struct B : A { };
```

That's fine! Providing a default constructor would be ill-formed for "B", because it would not be able to call the base-class' constructor. But the default constructor (and the other special functions) is only provided (we say it's *implicitly defined*) if it's actually needed.

Comment: I guess you could argue that in the case of an empty class, the compiler also adds at least one byte of padding ;-)

Answer (score 3):

From C++11 onwards, in addition to what you have listed

- Move ctor
- Move assignment operator

Answer (score 1):

Your list is complete. This is all it is adding.

Answer (score -1):

The list is not completed............
In addition with the above mention FOUR properties , there is an address operator ( & ) overloaded method , that return the address of the invoking object , is also provided automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

There are five properties:

constructor

copy constructor

destructor

assignment operator

the reference operator(&) - the address